# Display image like UICollectionView in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I have one trouble now I m currently using xcode 4.2, it won't support **UICollectionView**. I have bunch of images want to display like UICollectionView and also want to select multiple images with checkmark like UICollectionView. Any body know any way.. Please suggest me..

Comment: Update your XCode, or use `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @FahriAzimov:I can't update, then how can I done with scrollview. Multiple select how can I done

Comment: @user2922837:Me too ve. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use PSTCollectionView available [here](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

Inside there should be some example projects.